# how to get array format from mysql result with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to get array format from mysql database.
Example,Let I have **name table**.

*Name Table*

```
Id    name

1    jone
2    smith
3   waiyan
```

I want to get this data array form.

```
$name=array('jone','smith','waiyan');(//I want to get this format)
```

How can get this result? I am beginner for php.Please answer me.Thank your contribute.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Start with http://nz.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Thank for your instruction,Now I am trying with your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM your_table");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r["name"];
    //OR
    array_push($rows, $r['name']);
}
print_r($rows);
```

See: [mySQL PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Don't use `array_push` to push single elements. `$array[] = $element;` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Check here for info about the mysql functions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

For the specific task you're asking about, something like this should do it:

```
$result = msql_query('YOUR QUERY'); // returns a result resource
if ($result === false)  
{
    // handle the error
}

$names = array();
// get each row from your result one-by-one
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $names[] = $row['name']; // the keys in $row are named like your mysql columns
}
```